# Convert bmp image into DICOM

Tags: python, vtk, dicom, gdcm

I have 800 images in BMP format and I would like to convert them into DICOM. I have started like this, but it is not working for some reason.

My experience with VTK is limited:

```
file_in = 'C:/programfile/image.bmp'
file_out = 'test1.dcm'
vtkGDCMImageReader()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is in python:

```
r = vtkBMPReader()
r.SetFileName( 'test1.bmp' )

w = vtkGDCMImageWriter()
w.SetInput( r.GetOutput() )
w.SetFileName( 'test1.dcm' )
w.Write()
```

If your input BMP uses lookup table, you can simply pass it:

```
r = vtkBMPReader()
r.SetFileName( 'test1.bmp' )
r.Allow8BitBMPOn()
r.Update()
r.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetScalars().SetLookupTable( r.GetLookupTable() )

w = vtkGDCMImageWriter()
w.SetInput( r.GetOutput() )
w.SetFileName( 'test1.dcm' )
w.SetImageFormat( VTK_LOOKUP_TABLE );
w.Write()
```

And the opposite (DICOM -> BMP):

```
r = vtkGDCMImageReader()
r.SetFileName( 'test1.dcm' )

w = vtkBMPWriter()
w.SetInput( r.GetOutput() )
w.SetFileName( 'test1.bmp' )
w.Write()
```

Of course you can do it from the command line, simply use [gdcm2vtk](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/gdcm2vtk.html):

```
$ gdcm2vtk input.bmp output.dcm
```

or

```
$ gdcm2vtk --palette-color input.bmp output.dcm
```